# RGB Color Match

Tags: website-design, adobe-indesign

I am designing some banners and graphics for a client's website and I am finding it hard to find clean bright colours. I am using Adobe Indesign on an imac. I am saving all as jpegs in RGB. The worst is the bar of orange I have on her site (and also the blue) They end out coming darker and muted. I am looking for a bright, true orange and it comes out almost burnt umber - brownish - on client's website, even though it looks like a nice bright orange on the jpeg on my imac screen/monitor. I am using RGB colour in my swatches as well, and have tried several combinations but nothing. Also trying to get a nice bright blue, almost turquoise. Any ideas or help?
[image]

Comment: Could you provide screenshots?

Comment: Sure, first time using this site though. How do I upload a screenshot here?

Comment: Is your color profile set to srgb?

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to just use Illustrator or Photoshop for static web images.

However, if using Indesign and the output is RGB, you'll want to ensure the **Transparency Blend Space** is set to RGB.

`Edit > Transparency Blend Space > Document RGB`

[image]

This has a great deal of effect when exporting from InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets see. You create an image with bright colours, and when these are displayed on a website, they become murky?

- Open the jpgs in a few different browsers on your machine and see if
  they turn out different than from your original.
- Check a few different monitors/machines too, to see if it is consistent
  good/bad
- Check with your client if the content management system compresses
  images

Comment: I was also wondering, since orange seems to be a difficult color, if anyone had a certain color combo that they thought was a good one?

Comment: I see your point, but first you need to eliminate all other variables, So check browsers, previews, monitors.  There will be variations from screen to screen, machine to machine and browser to browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about color profiles mismatching. When your image is ready to be flatten, try to do this steps:
1. Edit -> Assign Profile -> Adobe RGB (1998). After that do
2. Edit -> Convert to Profile -> sRGB IEC61966-2.1.
3. Save your image and it will be bright on all platforms.